# Mapping array with Dataframe in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to write a code to convert the array.
The base array is a kind of permutated array, which has arrays inside as components.

```
el = {[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1] ... [4, 4, 3], [4, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4]}
125-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:

em = {"[0, 0, 0]", "[1, 0, 0]", "[0, 0, 1]" ... "[4, 4, 3]", "[4, 3, 4]", "[3, 4, 4]", "[4, 4, 4]"}
125-element Array{String,1}:
```

It represents how many stepped forward groups have.
And there is a sort of `dataframe`

3×3 Named Array{String,2}.; I used `NamedArrays` to depict its row name.

```
OrderNA = 
|row name  |Start | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd  |Finish|
|:-------- |:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:| ----:|
|    G1    | "Stt"| "W1" | "W2" | "W3" | "Fin"|
|    G2    | "Stt"| "W2" | "W3" | "W1" | "Fin"|
|    G3    | "Stt"| "W3" | "W1" | "W2" | "Fin"|
```

As you can see, It's a order table.

As mentioned, El's components represents location of groups.

And should be converted with the order table.

eg) [0,0,0] is location of [G1, G2, G3] => ["Stt","Stt","Stt"]

[1,0,0] => ["W1", "Stt", "Stt"]

[1,2,4] => ["W1", "W3", "Fin" ]

So I've struggled to convert it as described below, but I failed.

```
function trans(em)
    for i in 1:length(em)
        for j  in 1:length(em[i])
            @show em[i][j]
            if em[i][3j-1] == '0'
                replace(em[i][3j-1]) = "Stt"
            elseif em[i][3j-1] == '1'
                replace(em[i][j]) = OrderNA[j, 1]
            elseif em[i][3j-1] == '2'
                replace(em[i][3j-1]) = OrderNA[j, 2]
            elseif em[i][3j-1] == '3'
                replace(em[i][3j-1]) = OrderNA[j, 3]
                else em[i][3j-1] == '4'
                replace(em[i][3j-1]) = "Fin"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

syntax: ""em[i][((3 * j) - 1)]" is not a valid function argument name around In[90]:9

I can't figure out what wrong is. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: there should be no boolean after `else` that's what the error is referring to.

Comment: I made a simple mistake and I'm handling with it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
el_new = []
for (a,b,c) in el
    push!(el_new, [OrderNA[1, a+1], OrderNA[2, b+1], OrderNA[3, c+1]])
end
```